# Menu button disappears in mobile screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a portfolio website. The hamburger disappears when I open website on mobile phone.
when I inspect website on laptop screen it appears as desired in mobile mode (small screen)  as well in tablet mode. However it disappears when I open actual  website on mobile phone.
Can somebody help me to identify the problem?

https://pranalee.vercel.app/

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Works on my phone

Comment: I would do a loder so that all assets on the page are loaded and ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested on my iPhone 12, and I see the problem. What if you change the section1_header's `top: -100%;` to `top: -100vh;`?

I think it is just a positioning issue, try changing the unit.

Comment: Thank you so much @Lu Chih Yuan.  I spent lot time to solve this. It is working now. You can check on your iphone .